# Null set returned by mongodb aggregate Cursor in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

MongoDB aggregate query returning empty set .Below is the query i am using in a php script to  retrieve data from mongoDB .Please let me know where i am going wrong.

```
  $result = $collection->aggregateCursor([[ '$match'=> [ 'date'=> [ '$gte'=>ISODate("2015-06-01T00:00:00Z"), '$lte'=>ISODate("2015-06-03T00:00:00Z")] ] ],[ '$group'=> [ '_id'=> '$date', 'count'=> [ '$sum'=>1 ] ] ]]);
```

If i run same query in mongoDB shell.it is showing  the output as expected.

```
  db.mnumber.aggregate([{ $match: { date: { $gte:new ISODate("2015-06-01T00:00:00Z"), $lte:new ISODate("2015-06-03T00:00:00Z") } } },{ $group: { _id: "$date", 'count': { $sum:1 } } }])
    { "_id" : ISODate("2015-06-01T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 10000 }
    { "_id" : ISODate("2015-06-02T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 10000 }
    { "_id" : ISODate("2015-06-03T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 10000 }
```

### Sample data in collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55743941789a9abe7f4af3fd"),
        "msisdn" : "1234567890",
        "act_date" : ISODate("2014-11-24T00:00:00Z"),
        "date" : ISODate("2015-06-07T00:00:00Z"),
        "recharge_stats" : {
                "recharge_amt" : 0,
                "rechargetype" : "WEB"
        },
        "voice_usage" : {
                "local_og_mou" : 20,
                "local_other_mobile_og_mou" : 0,
                "nld_og_mou" : 0,
                "nld_other_mobile_og_mou" : 10
        },
        "gprs_usage" : {
                "total_access_count" : 1,
                "total_datavolume_mb" : 42
        },
        "sms_usage" : {
                "freesms" : 3,
                "local_sms_count" : 0,
                "nat_sms_count" : 0,
                "inter_sms_count" : 0
        },
        "campaign_details" : {
                "camp_id" : "M01124",
                "message" : "Hello .",
                "msg_id" : "9174051951412054925609431100",
                "cmp_activation_status" : "YES"
        }
}
```

Comment: Not a fan of PHP array syntax and not fully versed in the latest revision syntax (so not sure about that structure there ). But mainly, I thought [MongoDate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) was the MongoDB date contructor to use here and not `ISODate` for which I find no PHP reference at all. Your own function perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate a **[`MongoDate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php)** object as follows

```
$dateFrom = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-06-01T00:00:00Z"));
$dateTo = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-06-03T00:00:00Z"));
```

which you can then use in your aggregation pipeline instead of the MongoDB ISODate objects in your PHP query.

```
/* Run the command cursor */
$result = $collection->aggregateCursor(
    [
        [ '$match' => [ 'date'=> [ '$gte' => $dateFrom, '$lte' =>  $dateTo ]  ] ],
        [ '$group' => [ '_id' => '$date', 'count' => [ '$sum' => 1 ] ] ]            
    ]        
);
```

Comment: hi Chridam ,

Done changes with MongoDate() but now it is raising timeout errors as below.

 Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message '192.x.x.x:10002: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds' in C:\wamp\www\subscriber_details\cman.php on line 71

Comment: @SaikumarA Try to set `MongoCursor::$timeout = -1` (-1 is no timeout) before you call `aggregateCursor()`. For more information please refer to the [**documentation**](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php).

Comment: Hey Thanks Guys. Got the expected results.